# TeXstudio (2.9.4): Doesn't stop rerunning for references and citations

Tags: errors, pdftex, texstudio

I am using TeXstudio 2.9.4 as my LaTex editor. Most of time I just re-compile (using `F6`) but once every while I re-built (using `F1`) the whole project. This was working until now. Whereas compiling still works fine and "*exits normally* ", building won't terminate but instead showing repetiviely in the editor's *messages* tab only:

```
Rerunning for cross references and citations

Rerunning for cross references and citations
```

..

When I manually cancel/stop building, it terminates with:

```
Error: Command crashed: "make" pdf

Process exited normally
```

(in fact calling only `make pdf` in a shell will trigger the same behaviour)

I don't recall adding or changing anything but simple text and bib references since the last built.

I was using `make pdf` instead of `txs:///pdflatex` due to some quirks that now and then occured. Using the latter again seems to work and doesn't produce any errors.
Quite frankly I don't understand the difference between both commands - both should work in the same way.

Reading TeXstudio's [manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html) didn't help much in understanding nor did a search for some more detailed explanations.

Thus my questions: What causes the error?

..and implicetely: Is `make pdf` a replacement for `txs:///pdflatex`?

Answer (score 1):

`txs:///pdflatex` is the TXS-internal name for the pdflatex call (the command specified in Options -> Commands -> PDFLaTeX).

`make` is a general purpose build management tool, which runs task that are specified in a makefile. There are standard makefiles for building latex, but TXS does not ship these, so you'll probably have added it yourself (or received it together with the document).

Both are different ways to finally call pdflatex with appropriate arguments, but they have nothing to do with each other.

I can't say anything about your specific makefile, but from what you are telling, it seems like you have some undefined cross references or citations in your document. make checks the log/auxiliary latex files realizes that these are missing and triggers a recompile, which will result in an infinite loop. So, likely the effect results from a malformed document (missing ref/citation) in combiniation with an non-error-proof makefile.